Multiple names in a point

New to QGIS. Is there a way to create a Point with multiple Names in a column?

Use a point layer plus a separate data-only layer, than create a virtual layer.


Apart from the point layer, use a separate data-only layer (vector layer of type No geometry) which contains all the names plus an id-field that references the point to which the name belongs to.

Create a relation between the layers: Menu Project > Properties > Relations (see 2nd screenshot below for details).

Depending on what exactly you want to achieve, use the expression relation_aggregate(), e.g. to get a concatenated list of all the names associated with a point (in the screenshot below e.g. used to create a label):
 relation_aggregate( 
   'connect_names_to_points',   -- name of the relation
   'concatenate',
   "name", -- fieldname
   concatenator:=','
 )



The names in these labels were created with the expression from above:

This is how you create the relation - use a name for the relation for referencing it in the expression:


This answer is excellent for getting the job done with QGIS! From a more theoretical point of view one could add that you are now modeling a 1:n relationship between a household and its members. You can now store data that describes the household as a whole (e.g. type of roof, type of water supply, ...) on the household table and data that is only valid for a certain household member (e.g. name, date of birth, occupation) on the member table. If one wants to dig deeper relevant terms would be "ER (entity relationship) modeling" or "database normal forms".

Yes, that was indeed the intention, creating an entity relationship model database-like solution. It's great that QGIS offers such easy options to do so.

In an attribute table, one row refers to one feature (in your case a point feature).
So, you have the choice of having four points (at the exact same location) with individual values. The result is an attribute table as shown in your screenshot. Or you can aggregate values into one feature (e.g. comma separated values for the attribute "Name" of your point feature: 'Alex, Patricia, Bob, Ashley').
For the latter, you can use the tool "Aggregate" in QGIS.
